# Vuetifyjs how to set custom RGBA color?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

As [explained here](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme#customizing) vuetify colors can be customized as

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#3f51b5',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
  }
})
```

**but how can I use a custom RGBA color?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuetify's creators have said there is not their priorities to implement this feature...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pseudo-class: `::after` or `::before` ,set `background:var(--v-background-base);` and `opacity:0.4;`.

for example:

```
  .liveServer__title {
    position: relative;
    &::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--v-background-base);
      opacity: 0.4;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As zhao yue pointed out you can use ::after selector to achieve this, an example here:

https://codepen.io/amaieras/pen/QWZoEEE

```
 <div>
    <h1>some h1 text</h1>
    <h2>
       <span>some h2 text</span>
    </h2>
 </div>



h1 {
  background: rgba(255,0,0, 0.2);
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
}
h2 span {
  position: relative;
}
h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```